# Retrieving IDs of child pages which are in a different post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query

I have a normal page, which has subpages in a custom post type. I've tried to get_pages based on the child_of parameter but it returns nothing.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: May be you could paste the code you tried?

Comment: Please update the question with the relevant code for better visualization of the problem

Answer (score 0):

After some Google searches, I found all I needed to do was set the custom_post_type registration to include hierarchical => true and this solved my problem.